# How to express 64-bit integers in Swift?

Tags: swift, integer

I'm doing an exercise which requires producing 64-bit positive integers in Swfit, but I have no idea how that can be achieved. My machine is 64-bit for sure, but my test code cannot even produce 63-bit prositive integers.

Using `Double` may solve the problem, but that's not what the exercise intends to be. Is there any solution for this issue? Thank you.

The test code is as follows:

```
import Foundation

func numberOfGrainsOnChessBoard () {
    let ar = Array(1...64) 
    let arr = ar.map{twoMultipliedNTimes($0)}
    var index = 1
    for i in arr {
      print("\(index): \(i)")
      index = index + 1
    }
}
func twoMultipliedNTimes (_ times: Int) -> UInt64 {
    var product : UInt64 = 1;

    for _ in 1...times {
        product = product * 2
    }
    return product
}
addGrainsOnChessBoard()
```

The above code got an overflown error.

Comment: you haven't heard of `UInt64`?

Comment: I know it and used it in the test, but it was overflown.

Comment: `UInt64` represents 2^64 numbers, but ranging from `0` (all zeroes) to `2^64-1` (all ones), so `2^64` - last iteration of the loop when `times == 64` - overflows it

Comment: `for _ in 1..<times {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will generate random Int64 bits integers between it's minimum and it's maximum value. So you can change the range to fit your needs.

```swift
let myInt: Int64 = Int64.random(in: Int64.min...Int64.max)
```